# Print a specific row and row+1 based on column value in Python Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, if-statement

I have a python dataframe as shown below, I am trying to access rows based on value of column C. When Column C==1, I want to print the corresponding row and row+1 side by side as shown in expected output below. Please note when there are continuous 1's it should print multiple pairs as shown below in expected result.

Input Dataframe:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| F | M | 1 |
| S | P | 3 |
| a | c | 1 |
| h | g | 1 |
| k | j | 2 |
| c | p | 4 |
| q | b | 1 |
| S | P | 1 |
| F | z | 1 |
| q | z | 2 |

Expected Output Format:

```
1. F, M, 1; S, P, 3
2. a, c, 1; h, g, 1
3. h, g, 1; k, j, 2 
4. q, b, 1; S, P, 1
5. S, P, 1; F, z, 1
6. F, z, 1; q, z, 1
```

I was trying to doing something like:

```
if (df['c'] == 1):
  print...
```

I see following error:
`ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`.

Please help me with some ideas to print the pattern described. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to add columns with the next row's values, and print just those line who fill the condition:

```
df['A_next'] = df['A'].shift(-1)
df['B_next'] = df['B'].shift(-1)
new_df = df[df['C'] == 1]
print(new_df)
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped. Just .shift() gives previous row, instead .shift(periods =-1) worked for me to solve the above problem.

Comment: @Sandeep Right. Edited the answer, for whoever enters it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

there is easier way
you can make a new dataframe based on what you want
and use it !!!

this is the code:

```
column_name = 'C'
desired_value = '1'
filtered_rows = df[df[column_name] == desired_value]
print (filtered_rows)
```